# Guttenburg and Classic Editor - How to use the custom guttenburg block in classic editor?

Tags: php, block-editor

I am making a theme, in that I have created some custom blocks for guttenburg but the problem is how the user can use the guttenburg blocks if he/she switches to classic editor.

For an example,

Let suppose I have created a button block ( I know it's already there ) but a custom one so how the user is able to access it, when he/she swithces to the classic editor.

Is it really possible or not. If yes than how.

Comment: It’s not possible. This is why the block editor was created. If it were possible, then the block editor wouldn’t be necessary.

Comment: @JacobPeattie but what is the purpose of creating the custom block if a user cannot use it with the classic editor. So what should i do if a user ask me that he/she cannot access the blocks in classic editor.

Comment: If they are using the classic editor then they have chosen not to have access to blocks. That’s the choice they’re making. The block editor is the new editor and has new features. Custom blocks are one of those features. If they want access to new features they can’t use the old thing. It’s not that complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to provide your custom blocks with an additional plugin. You can [add it automatically](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107009/automatically-install-wordpress-plugin-at-theme-activation). If your users ever change their theme again, they won't be able to edit their content anymore.
As mentioned in the comments, block features belong to the block editor. Your users should know that. They decide proactively to disclaim the block editor.

In cases as simple as your example button block you can provide a shortcode. If you want it badly ;)