# Automatically download, install and activate plugins that my plugin depends, how?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm developing a plugin that requires a couple of plugins from WordPress repository to work correctly.

Is it possible to download and install from WordPress repository and activate one or more plugin that my custom plugin requires automatically on plugin activation?

There is a safe and correct way to do this via PHP?

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107009/automatically-install-wordpress-plugin-at-theme-activation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would you require and automatically download dependent plugins?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24717/how-would-you-require-and-automatically-download-dependent-plugins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TGMPA is a useful php class to perform the required actions: http://tgmpluginactivation.com/

Comment: I'll try it, thank you!

Comment: It (almost) works!

Comment: There is a number of issues with TGMPA, and no active development for several years.

Answer (score 4):

In addition with Andrea Somovigo's answer, this is a list of services and open sources that might be useful:

- [WP Package Editor](https://wordpress.recuweb.com/)

> WP2E is a service allowing developers to create and manage installation
> packages to deliver and maintain sets of interdependent themes and
> plugins.

- [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/)

> TGM Plugin Activation is a PHP library that allows you to easily
> require or recommend plugins for your WordPress themes (and plugins).

- [WPFavs](https://wpfavs.com/)

> It is a Free WordPress plugin manager and bulk installation tool

- [WordPress Packagist](https://wpackagist.org/)

> This site mirrors the WordPress plugin and theme directories as a
> Composer repository.

- [WP Plugin Dependencies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-dependencies/)

> This meta-plugin allows regular plugins to specify other plugins that
> they depend upon.

- [WP Dependency Installer](https://github.com/afragen/wp-dependency-installer)

> A lightweight class to add to WordPress plugins/themes to
> automatically install plugin dependencies.